# Как оптимизировать панель администратора в Django?

Tags: django, оптимизация, django-admin

Как вы уже наверное знаете, в Django существует встроенная админ-панель. Но мне не очень нравиться еë внешний вид, и мне надо добавить в неë дополнительную функцию. Собственно, вот и вопрос: как оптимизировать панель администратора в Django (то есть изменить еë внешний вид и добавить новые функции)?

Comment: Я вам уже говорил конкретные вопросы писать, а вы всё так и продолжаете клепать невнятные и слишком общие...

Comment: Я спросил, как изменить вид и настроить функционал админ-панели в Django. Что тут непонятного?

Comment: А вы что - модератор на этом сайте?

Comment: Админ-панель - штука большая и сложная, состоящая из десятков (а может и сотен) разных компонентов, к каждому из которых нужен свой индивидуальный подход. Непонятно, что конкретно вы хотите изменить и какую конкретно (или хотя бы примерно) функцию вы хотите добавить

Comment: Я создаю сайт, на котором пользователи могут выкладывать форографии. Мне нужно, чтобы я войдя в панель администратора мог блокировать изображения, которые имеют непристойный характер.

Comment: Зачем для этого изменять админ-панель? Достаточно добавить отметку о блокировке в ту модель, которая хранит изображения

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что если все изображения хранятся в определëнном каталоге, то можно просто изменить фотографию?

Comment: А как с помощью админ-панели блокировать пользователей?

Comment: К файлам в каталоге неприменимо понятие "блокировать" (такой функции не существует в файловых системах), так что непонятно, что вы собрались с ними делать, если вас поле в модели чем-то не устраивает

Comment: У любого пользователя есть поле is_active, которое отображается в админке как галочка "Активен"

Comment: А если я уберу эту галочку, пользователь будет заблокирован?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/admin-interface/) можно подробней ознакомится со всеми админ-интерфейсами `django`.
Я покажу установку и настройку на примере админ-интерфейса `django-grapelli`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы установить данную панель надо выполнить команду:

```
pip install django-grappelli
```

После установки открываем файл `settings.py` и добавляем `grappelli` в `INSTALLED_APPS` (перед `django.contrib.admin`):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Далее добавляем `grappelli` в файл `urls.py` папки конфигурации :

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # admin site
]
```

Добавляем обработчик контекстного запроса:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Сохраняем и закрываем файлы `settings.py` и `urls.py`, пересобираем статику для медиафайлов:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Запускаем сервер `python manage.py runserver` переходим в админку и тестим. Это не решает вопрос блокировок пользователей, но полностью отвечает на вопрос изменения внешнего вида административной панели `django`.